# What command to run to change lock permissions on a user

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, terminal

Im trying to export a DB on amazons RDS but whenever i run the mysqldump command i get the error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'ec2'@'%' to database ‘DB_name’ when using LOCK TABLES
```

I dont know the right command to run in my mac terminal to change the lock permissions for the user.

can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding " --single-transaction "

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -u root mydbname > backup.sql
```

> mysqldump requires at least the SELECT privilege for dumped tables,
>   SHOW VIEW for dumped views, TRIGGER for dumped triggers, and LOCK
>   TABLES if the --single-transaction option is not used.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: it doesn't give an error when i add --single-transaction but doesn't give me the sql file. I'm new with running commands on the terminal. i connect to the ec2 instance then i run the mysqldump command. should i be doing another step before running the mysqldump?

Comment: Can you give me the exact command with options you are using?

Comment: this is the command I'm running mysqldump --single-transaction -(db instance endpoint) -uec2 -p(password) DBname> ~/Applications

Comment: I'm assuming you are running an ec2 instance/default mysql port 3306 is open and you are doing this on your mac. After using the following (filling in your values including chaging the host -h value) the file backup.sql will be in your ~/Applications folder                  mysqldump --single-transaction -h ec2-20-20-109-12.compute-1.amazonaws.com -umysqlusername -pmysqlpassword  dbname > ~/Applications/backup.sql

Comment: i really appreciate your help and your assumptions were all correct. first i realised i didn't add the 'backup.sql' at the end of the directory path, so i added it and got the error -bash: /home/ec2-user/Applications/backup.sql: Not a directory. which is correct because its not my computers directory. then i just had the directory as '/backup.mysql' and got the error: -bash: /backup.sql: Permission denied then tried 'backup.mysql' as the directory (without the slash) it diddnt give me any errors or a file, basically nothing happened.